# ¿Como puedo poner una restriccion para que un atributo sea solamente en mayúsuculas?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy con sql y nos piden que un atributo tenga de restriccion que solo se puede almacenar en mayúsucula, la cosa es que pensandolo solo me sale de esta manera:

Esta es la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_INSTITUTOS(
    codigo_centro int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(20) not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TABLA_INSTITUOS PRIMARY KEY (codigo_centro)
);
```

Aquí la restricción de donde sale mi pregunta:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLA_INSTITUTOS
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_NOMBRE_MAYUSCULA CHECK (like UPPER(nombre));
```

Y es eso, como podría poner la frase de arriba correctamente si a la hora de hacer un insert que lo hiciese de forma correcta.

Comment: MySql Server 8.0

Comment: Vale, a la hora de añadir la restricción la cual yo he puesta esta, pero sé que esta mal: ALTER TABLE TABLA_INSTITUTOS
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_NOMBRE_MAYUSCULA CHECK (like UPPER(nombre)); y quisiera saber cual es la forma correcta de ponerla, para cuando yo haga un insert si lo pongo en minuscula me lo reconozca

Comment: eso mismo de forma directa, pero ya he probado y parece que me acepta el constraint de esta manera, era un fallo mio de ponerlo todo dentro del check: ALTER TABLE TABLA_INSTITUTOS
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_NOMBRE_MAYUSCULA CHECK(nombre like UPPER(nombre));

Answer (score 3):

Lo mas simple en estos casos sería directamente pasar la cadena a transformar al método [`UPPER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) de esta forma:

```
INSERT INTO Tabla (columna) VALUES(UPPER('Valor'));
```

Pero si no deseas que manualmente tengas que introducir al juego dicha función, puedes construir un trigger de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER transforma BEFORE INSERT ON TABLA_INSTITUTOS
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET New.nombre = UPPER(NEW.nombre);
    END;
//
```

Donde:

- Ocurrirá [antes de hacer el `INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- Hacemos uso del prefijo `NEW` y el nombre de la columna `nombre` para acceder al [nuevo valor insertado](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)
- Asignamos como valor al registro que será insertado el valor nuevo transformado por la función `UPPER`

Answer (score 1):

Dado que lo que te piden es que haya una **restricción**, esto generalmente significa que debe haber una forma **declarativa** de restringir el valor ingresado, de manera que solamente se acepten mayúsculas.

Las restricciones de restricción, se expresan, en el modelo relacional con un **`constraint`** de tipo **`check`** y podrías declararlo de la siguiente manera:

```
alter table TABLA_INSTITUTOS
  add constraint CK_NOMBRE_MAYUSCULA 
check (nombre = upper(nombre));
```

Las restricciones de tipo `check`, aceptarán solamente aquellos registros para los cuales la evaluación de la expresión del `constraint` devuelva `true`, y la expresión `nombre = upper(nombre)` devolverá true solamente si el valor ingresado se encuentra en mayúsculas.

He escrito esta respuesta a pesar de existir otras, incluso con votos a favor y que resuelven de una manera u otra el *problema*, ninguna ha tenido el cuidado de atender el requerimiento puntual que está en la pregunta. En mi opinión, al tener un requerimiento puntual, el modelo **debe** cumplirlo, y la única forma de cumplir con una restricción de este tipo es con una restricción declarativa.

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear un trigger que se active siempre que crearas un registro, ejemplo

```
//primero creamos la tabla
CREATE TABLE data (
  name varchar(100)
);

// luego el trigger
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig_name_check BEFORE INSERT ON data
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.name REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$' = 0 THEN 
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'solo mayusculas!!!';
END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

y probamos, debería pasar mas o menos lo siguiente para cada caso

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('A'); -- OK
INSERT INTO data VALUES ('a'); -- error: #1644
```

esta solución la obtuve de
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005283/is-it-possible-to-enforce-data-checking-in-mysql-using-regular-expression

Comment: porque no solo usas UPPER( myvalor ) ? al momento de hacer el insert