# Error en un trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Hola amigos es que tengo un trigger que no me funciona y me sale un error

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarNota` 
  AFTER INSERT ON `grades_validation` 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE grades_validation 
    SET grade = Replace(grade,".",",") 
    where ID = new.id_grade
```

El error que me sale es:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'grades_validation' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
> this stored function/trigger

No entiendo, que es eso?

Comment: explica mejor que es lo que deseas lograr

Comment: Un trigger no permite que hagas operaciones en la misma tabla sobre la que está operando. Esto para evitar operaciones en cascada que se replicarían hasta el fin de los tiempos... para lo que pareces intentar hacer, con modificar el contenido de new **before insert** es suficiente. Modifícalo y deja que se inserte ya modificado.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se haga un insert en la tabla grades_validation quiero que todos los . de la columna grade se cambien por ,

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo poner una restriccion para que un atributo sea solamente en mayúsuculas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390753/como-puedo-poner-una-restriccion-para-que-un-atributo-sea-solamente-en-may%c3%basucu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba simplemente con:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarNota` 
  BEFORE INSERT ON `grades_validation` 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  SET new.grade = REPLACE(new.grade,".",",");
```

No es necesario que estés en un disparador, MySQL se queja incluso cuando hacer un `UPDATE` de campos que afectan al `WHERE` y hay que ingeniárselas con un `JOIN`. En el caso de un disparador lo tienes un poco más fácil con las variables `new.campo`

Ya me confirmas si era eso o tenemos que darle alguna vuelta más. En ese caso, modifica la pregunta explicando las funciones de `ID` e `id_grade` en tu tabla.

Respondiendo a tu comentario, con que ejecutes esta query antes de almacenar el disparador, ya deberías poder quedarte tranquilo.

```
  UPDATE grades_validation
    SET grade = REPLACE(grade,".",",");
```

Con el disparador activo, ya nadie podrá registrar una coma en ese campo. Si temes que alguien te haga un `UPDATE`, amplíalo para `BEFORE UPDATE` y ya tendrías todos los casos contemplados.

Comment: ME da este error "#1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger"

Comment: De hecho no importa si esta el where id = new.grade ya que lo que me interesa es que se actualice toda la columna de grade, que se cambie todas los (.) existentes por una (,)

Comment: Lo cambie con un before update y si me lo acepto mysql, pero el detalle que necesito que lo haga siempre despues de un insert

Comment: Perfecto, modifico la respuesta para contemplarlo. Realmente no necesitas hacer el `UPDATE` después de cada `INSERT`, pruébalo, ya verás...

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a David JP y Alfabravo pude solucionarlo era mas simple de lo que parecia como me comentaban.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `actualizarNota` BEFORE INSERT ON `grades_validation` FOR EACH ROW SET new.grade = Replace(new.grade,".",",")
```

Esta es la soluciòn al final me toco hacer el cambio a before ya que after genera un error.

Comment: Entonces es está o la otra la respuesta correcta, procura marcar como aceptada la solución final

Comment: Por otro lado está demás re publiques el código de David, con marcar su respuesta alcanza

Comment: Entiendoq ue pena soy muy nuevo en esto